# Subspace for 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the set of S of 2x2 matricies $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&0\end{bmatrix}$ such that a +2b+3c = 0.

Then S is 2D subspace of M2x2.

How do you get S is a 2 dimensional subspace of M2x2. I don't understand this. How do you determine this is 2 dimensional, there are no leading ones to base this of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about it is that you have two conditions. One of them being $a+2b+3c = 0$ and the other being that the element in the $(2,2)$ position is equal to zero. If your matrix was$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ the second condition would be $d = 0$. Because you have two conditions on a four dimensional space your subspace should have dimension $4-2 = 2$.

To continue the argument, write your matrix in the subspace as $x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3+x_4e_4$ where:

$$ e_1 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$$
$$ e_2 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1  \\ 0 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$$
$$ e_3 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0  \\ 1 & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$$
$$ e_4 = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1  \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Let $M$ be a matrix in your subspace. $M = x_1e_1 + x_2e_2 + x_3e_3+x_4e_4$. It should be clear that $x_4 = 0$ and that $x_1 = a$, $x_2 = b$ and $x_3 = c = \frac{-a-2b}{3}$.

We are left with only two free variables so the dimension of the subspace will be two.

Answer (score 3):

Since $a=-(2b+3c)$, we can write the matrices as $$\begin{bmatrix}-(2b+3c) & b\\c & 0\end{bmatrix}=b\begin{bmatrix}-2&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}-3&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ The two matrices above span the subspace (assuming you have verified that it *is* a subspace).

It is two-dimensional because two "vectors" (matrices in this case) span the "vector space." The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors which make up a basis for that space. You can also think of it as "degrees of freedom." In this instance we are effectively dealing with two variables - there are three, but the last one (I chose a) is determined by the other two.

Comment: May I add the (obvious) requirement that the OP needs to check that the two matrices that span $S$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @Martin Argerami Yes, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand how it is 2 dimensional subspace of M2x2. My main question was how do you determine what dimensional subspace it is. For example why is it not a 1D or 3D subspace.

Comment: @user137673: what's the definition of dimension?